# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Sequelize')

Tags: typescript, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm using express/postgres/sequelize/typescript and I've created this file containing 2 models. Stakeholders and Companies. I get no issues when fetching a list of companies or stakeholders (Company.findAll(), Stakeholder.findAll()).

But as soon as I create an association between these 2 models I get the error:`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Sequelize')`

I need to create a many2many relationship between these models through "Position". Ideally I would have individual files for each model and an index file making the sequelize connection and creating an instance although I can't find any example of how this index file should look like.

These are the versions:
"express": "^4.17.1",
"sequelize": "^6.20.0",
"pg": "^8.7.3",
"pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
"ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8",
"typescript": "^4.6.4"
"@types/node": "^17.0.35",
"@types/express": "^4.17.13",\

This is my file

```
import {Association, CreationOptional, DataTypes, ForeignKey, InferAttributes, InferCreationAttributes, Model, Sequelize} from 'sequelize'
import logger from '../utils/logger/logger'
import {ICompanyDelivery, ICompanyMarket, ICompanyPosBilling, ICompanySettlement, ICompanySubscription, ICompanyVolume, ICompanyWebsite} from '../types/company'

export const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://test:test@localhost:5432/board4')
const test = async () => {
  try {
    await sequelize.authenticate()
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.')
  } catch (error) {
    //@ts-ignore
    error('Unable to connect to the database:', error)
  }
}
test()

export class Company extends Model<InferAttributes<Company>, InferCreationAttributes<Company>> {
  declare companyId:CreationOptional<string>
  declare companyName:string
  declare companyEntityType:string | null
  declare companyVatNumber:string | null
  declare companyRegistrationNumber:string
  declare companyPubliclyListed:boolean | null
  declare companyDateOfIncorporation:Date | null
  declare companyAddress1:string | null
  declare companyAddress2:string | null
  declare companyCity:string | null
  declare companyPostCode:string | null
  declare companyCountry:string | null
  declare companyPhone:string | null
  declare companyEmail:string | null
  declare companyUrl:string | null
  declare companyLogoUrl:string | null
  declare createdAt:CreationOptional<Date>
  declare updatedAt:CreationOptional<Date>

  declare static associations:{
    stakeholders:Association<Company, Stakeholder>
  }
}

export class Stakeholder extends Model<InferAttributes<Stakeholder>, InferCreationAttributes<Stakeholder>> {
  declare stakeholderId:string
  declare stakeholderName:string
  declare username:string
  declare password:string
  declare stakeholderLastname:string
  declare stakeholderEmail:string
  declare stakeholderJobTitle?:string | null
  declare stakeholderSharesPercentage?:number | null
  declare stakeholderDOB?:string | null
  declare stakeholderNationality?:string | null
  declare stakeholderAddress1?:string | null
  declare stakeholderAddress2?:string | null
  declare stakeholderPostCode?:string | null
  declare stakeholderCity?:string | null
  declare stakeholderCountry?:string | null
  declare stakeholderPhone?:string | null
  declare stakeholderPassport?:string | null
  declare stakeholderProofOfAddress?:string | null
  declare stakeholderRole:string
  declare positionCompanyId:ForeignKey<string>

  declare createdAt:CreationOptional<Date>
  declare updatedAt:CreationOptional<Date>

  declare static associations:{
    companies:Association<Stakeholder, Company>
  }
}

Company.belongsToMany(Stakeholder, {through: 'Position', foreignKey: 'positionStakeholderId'})<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<This causes the issue
//Stakeholder.belongsToMany(Company, {through: 'Position', foreignKey: 'positionCompanyId'})

Company.init(
  {
    companyId: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    companyName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    companyEntityType: DataTypes.STRING,
    companyVatNumber: DataTypes.STRING,
    companyRegistrationNumber: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: {
        name: 'uniqueRegistrationNumber',
        msg: 'Company Registration number address already in use'
      },
      validate: {
        notNull: {msg: 'Must be a valid Registration number'}
      }
    },
    companyDateOfIncorporation: DataTypes.DATE,
    companyPubliclyListed: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    companyAddress1: DataTypes.STRING,
    companyAddress2: DataTypes.STRING,
    companyCity: DataTypes.STRING,
    companyPostCode: DataTypes.STRING,
    companyCountry: DataTypes.STRING,
    companyPhone: DataTypes.STRING,
    companyEmail: DataTypes.STRING,
    companyUrl: DataTypes.STRING,
    companyLogoUrl: DataTypes.STRING,
    createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
    updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE,
  },
  {
    sequelize: sequelize,
    underscored: true,
    timestamps: true,
    tableName: 'companies',
  }
)

Stakeholder.init(
  {
    stakeholderId: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    username: {
      allowNull: true,
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    password: {
      allowNull: true,
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    stakeholderRole: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    stakeholderName: DataTypes.STRING,
    stakeholderLastname: DataTypes.STRING,
    stakeholderJobTitle: DataTypes.STRING,
    stakeholderEmail: DataTypes.STRING,
    stakeholderSharesPercentage: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    stakeholderDOB: DataTypes.STRING,
    stakeholderNationality: DataTypes.STRING,
    stakeholderAddress1: DataTypes.STRING,
    stakeholderAddress2: DataTypes.STRING,
    stakeholderPostCode: DataTypes.STRING,
    stakeholderCity: DataTypes.STRING,
    stakeholderCountry: DataTypes.STRING,
    stakeholderPhone: DataTypes.STRING,
    stakeholderPassport: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      set: function (val:any) {
        logger.debug(`${__filename}:${val} is valid?: ${val.fileName && val.fileName.split('.')[1] !== 'undefined'}`)
        if (val.fileName && val.fileName.split('.')[1] !== 'undefined') this.setDataValue('stakeholderPassport', val.fileName)
      }
    },
    stakeholderProofOfAddress: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      set: function (val:any) {
        logger.debug(`${__filename}:${val} is valid?: ${val.fileName && val.fileName.split('.')[1] !== 'undefined'}`)
        if (val.fileName && val.fileName.split('.')[1] !== 'undefined') this.setDataValue('stakeholderProofOfAddress', val.fileName)
      }
    },
    createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
    updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE,

  },
  {
    sequelize: sequelize,
    timestamps: true,
    tableName: 'stakeholders'
  }
)
```